# How to prevent string.TrimStart OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, out-of-memory

How can I rewrite this method to prevent/avoid OutOfMemoryException? .NET 4.5

```
private static string RemoveUnparsableCharacters(string content)
{
    return content.TrimStart(new char[] { Convert.ToChar(65279) });
}
        
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
at System.String.InternalSubString(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
at System.String.TrimHelper(Char[] trimChars, Int32 trimType)
at System.String.TrimStart(Char[] trimChars)
at X.X.X.RemoveUnparsableCharacters(String content)
```

I tried to benchmark various methods with BenchmarkDotNet, but I noticed that `TrimStart` method doesn't seem to allocate a lot

**but on the other hand that Exception was thrown on .NET 4.5 meanwhile my benchmark was run on .NET (Core) 5, huh. gotta check this again**

```
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class Test
{
    private readonly string text = "";
    private char WhiteChar = Convert.ToChar(65279);

    public Test()
    {
        text = File.ReadAllText(@"..\..\..\..\input.txt");
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public string A()
    {
        return string.Join("", text.Skip(1)); // random method just to check whether this test works
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public string B()
    {
        return text.TrimStart(new char[] { WhiteChar });
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<Test>();
    }
}
```

---

```
| Method |             Mean |          Error |         StdDev |      Gen 0 |    Gen 1 |    Gen 2 |    Allocated |
|------- |-----------------:|---------------:|---------------:|-----------:|---------:|---------:|-------------:|
|      A | 45,675,100.00 ns | 904,248.534 ns | 888,092.970 ns | 11545.4545 | 363.6364 | 363.6364 | 55,179,590 B |
|      B |         10.67 ns |       0.290 ns |       0.387 ns |     0.0076 |        - |        - |         32 B |
```

Comment: Well, how much text is in `content`? How are you getting that string in the first place? If you're reading it from a stream, you could skip those characters while reading instead of trimming them afterwards.

Comment: Seems like your file is huge. Instead of loading it in one go with ReadAllText consider reading and processing it line-by-line. (or use a smaller text of course)

Comment: Content is content of HTTP request, it's json which has 1st `weird` character that makes Json parser throw Exception since it doesn't recognize this character and I wrote method that just removes it, but that method seems to do something internally which causes OOM. That json is indeed huge.

Comment: try to avoid the creation of the weird character instead to remove it in controller if possible.

Comment: It comes from external API, it's response

Comment: There are several misconceptions hidden in this code.  For one, .net core runs in 64-bit mode by default, 4.5 in 32-bit mode.  For another, the unit test doesn't actually test the failure scenario.  ReadAllText() has no trouble removing the BOM (called "whitechar" in the test).  In the code that actually fails and we cannot see, OOM is likely because TrimStart() doubles the memory usage.

Comment: @HansPassant `For another, the unit test doesn't actually test the failure scenario.` I agree, that was my first idea to try to replicate it

Comment: I would probably recommend using a stream to represent any large data. And StreamReader to read or peek at individual characters. Strings are immutable, so any change needs to allocate a completely new string, and that is probably not efficient when the data is very large.